# Commit multiple SqlCommands with SqlTransaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, sqltransaction

I am trying to pass a list of `SqlCommand` into a member function that holds the connection to the database.

```
public void CommitAsTransaction(List<SqlCommand> commands) {
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    SqlConnection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = this.CreateSqlConnection();
        connection.Open();

        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("TransactionID");

        foreach (SqlCommand cmd in commands) {
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

This is what I currently have. The error occurs because the command seems to be being executed as in place and the `transaction.Commit();` is never reached. I have seen many people doing it like this and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

PS: The issue is that the stored procedures that will be getting executed MUST all be run within a single transaction, I do not control these and they're encrypted, the reason they must be run in a transaction is because they create temp records in a table that has a PK requirement.

Comment: You say the commit is never reached. What happens instead?

Comment: Also, I believe I would put the connection and transaction into using blocks.

Comment: I get a SQL exception stating that their is a primary key contstraint on the temporary table, this means that the SqlCommand actually executed on the server.

Comment: What isolation level is configured on your SQL instance?

Comment: Transactions don't mean that the command doesn't execute until the commit - they mean that the commands execute immediately, but that their _affects_ won't be seen outside the transaction until the commit.

Comment: Hexadron, that's an assumption, but is not necessitated by the code you posted.  If you can include the SQL someone else might notice some other reason for the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much. I ended up figuring it out on my own based on other peoples combined answers, as a thank you here is the code I used:

```
public List<Models.eConnectModels.eConnStatus> CommitAsTransaction(List<SqlCommand> commands) 
{
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    List<eConnStatus> ErrorList = new List<eConnStatus>();
            
    try 
    {
        connection = this.CreateSqlConnection();
        connection.Open();
                
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted, "TransactionID");

        foreach (SqlCommand cmd in commands) 
        {
            eConnStatus curErr = new eConnStatus();
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            
            SqlParameter errorString = cmd.Parameters.Add("@oErrString", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            errorString.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            errorString.Size = 8000;

            SqlParameter errorStatus = cmd.Parameters.Add("@O_iErrorState", SqlDbType.Int);
            errorStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            curErr.ErrorState = (int)cmd.Parameters["@O_iErrorState"].Value;
            curErr.ErrorMessage = (string)cmd.Parameters["@oErrString"].Value;
            ErrorList.Add(curErr);
        }

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        connection.Close();
        throw ex;
    }
    
    connection.Close();
    return ErrorList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a transaction scope instead ?
Something like:

```
// place this code inside CommitAsTransaction

using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
     Boolean AllOK = true;
     SqlConnection connection = this.CreateSQLConnection();
     try
     {
         connection.Open()
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
       // deal with it how you need to
       AllOK = false;
     }

     if (AllOK)
     {
        foreach(SQlCommand cmd in Commands)
        {
            try
            {
                 cmd.Connection = connection;
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               // Deal with it.. 
               AllOK = false;
               break;
            }
        }

        if (AllOK)
        {
           scope.Complete();
           try
           {
               connection.Close();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
             // deal with it
           }
        }
    }
}
```